# How can I load a checkbox checked status from a mysql bool, and change the mysql bool in the database dynamically when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am building an internal error reporting system for a small non-profit. I have everything working that I promised my client, but I cannot seem to get the checkbox to have the behavior I desire. I want the checkboxes to load either checked or not based on the bool(tinyint) value in the mysql database. Then I need to dynamically update the database value when the status of the checkbox is changed by the user. A cherry on top would update the 'isactive' field of the database with the checked status as well. I tagged AJAX and Jquery because, although I don't know them, I believe they may be necessary for the task.

```
<?php
$errortypearray = ["Broken Link", "Broken Image", "English Usage", "Incorrect Results", 
"Unexpected Behavior", "Other"];
$priorityarray = ["Review", "Low", "Moderate", "High"];
$boolarray = ["Closed", "Active"];

// Below is optional, remove if you have already connected to your database.
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'a1b2c3D4', 'pcrerrors');

// For extra protection these are the columns of which the user can sort by (in your database table).
$columns = array('errorID','reporter','errortype','priority','description','recipient','reportdate');

// Only get the column if it exists in the above columns array, if it doesn't exist the database table will be sorted by the first item in the columns array.
$column = isset($_GET['column']) && in_array($_GET['column'], $columns) ? $_GET['column'] : $columns[0];

// Get the sort order for the column, ascending or descending, default is ascending.
$sort_order = isset($_GET['order']) && strtolower($_GET['order']) == 'desc' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

// Get the result...
if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM errors ORDER BY ' .  $column . ' ' . $sort_order)) {
    // Some variables we need for the table.
    $up_or_down = str_replace(array('ASC','DESC'), array('up','down'), $sort_order); 
    $asc_or_desc = $sort_order == 'ASC' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    $add_class = ' class="highlight"';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>PCR Error Portal</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
            <style>
            html {
                font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                min-width: 100px;
                width: 50%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                font-size: .55em;
            }
            th {
                background-color: rgba(0, 52, 133, 1);
                border: 1px solid #54585d;
            }
            th:hover {
                background-color: #64686e;
            }
            th:hover:last-child {
                background-color: #54585d;
            }
            th a {
                display: block;
                text-decoration:none;
                padding: 5px;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 13px;
            }
            th a i {
                margin-left: 5px;
                color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
            }
            td {
                padding: 10px;
                color: #636363;
                border: 1px solid #dddfe1;
            }
            tr {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
            tr .highlight {
                background-color: #f9fafb;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <img class="logo" name="pcrlogo" id="pcrlogo" src="https://politicalcandidatereference.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/pcr-logo02.png" width="360px">
            </div>
            <div class="subheader">
                <h1><strong>PCR Error Report</strong></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="tableContainer" >
                <table class="table" >
                    <tr>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=errorID&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">ErrorID<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'errorID' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=reporter&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Reporter<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'reporter' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=errortype&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Error Type<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'errortype' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=priority&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Priority<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'priority' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=description&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Error Description<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'description' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=recipient&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Assigned To<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'recipient' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=reportdate&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Date Reported<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'reportdate' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=isactive&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Status<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'isactive' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                        <th><a href="recordportal2.php?column=completed&order=<?php echo $asc_or_desc; ?>">Completed<i class="fas fa-sort<?php echo $column == 'completed' ? '-' . $up_or_down : ''; ?>"></i></a></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'errorID' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo $row['errorID']; ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'reporter' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo ucfirst($row['reporter']); ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'errortype' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo $errortypearray[$row['errortype']]; ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'priority' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo $priorityarray[$row['priority']]; ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'description' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'recipient' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo ucfirst($row['recipient']); ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'reportdate' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo $row['reportdate']; ?></td>
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'isactive' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><?php echo $boolarray[$row['isactive']]; ?></td>
                        <!-- The row below is what I need to fix, I want it to load with the checkbox checked or not depending upon the 0,1 value from the database 
                            After that is working, I need to make it so when the status of the checkbox is changed the status of the 'isactive' bool variable also changes -->
                        <td<?php echo $column == 'completed' ? $add_class : ''; ?>><input type="checkbox" checked="<?php echo ($row['completed'] == 0) ? "true" : "false"; ?>" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="subfooter"><p><a href="http://localhost:8088/PCRErrorReporting/PCRindex.html">Report Another Error</a></p>
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    $result->free();
}
?>
```

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: There are boundless examples of how to use AJAX on this site and on the internet in general. jQuery makes ajax super easy. You should research that, try something then come back to get help when it doesn't work

Comment: ___BIG Point___ If you want to know whats happened to a checkbox, it has to have a `name` attribute, otherwise it will not be sent from the browser with the other form data! I dont see a form either??

Comment: Welcome to SO. A search for "*php ajax update checkbox*" turns up many examples with working code here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .change jquery function?
Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<script>
   $('#check').change(function () {
     alert('changed');
   });
</script>
```